# 特定のユーザにアプリ内課金を無料で提供

Tags: ios, アプリ内課金

アプリ内課金で機能をアンロックすることを考えています。
アカウント登録して使用するアプリなのですが、招待制でアカウント同士がグループとして設定できるようになっています。
そのグループの代表者がアプリ内課金したら、他のメンバーも同様に機能をアンロックさせたいと考えています。
自前のサーバで、代表者が課金したことは分かるので
そのタイミングで他のメンバーの機能をアンロックさせることも可能だと考えてます。
ただ、その場合 App Storeの審査でリジェクトされないか心配しています。
調べてもあまり情報が出てこないのでご存じの方教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 質問の対象はコードの実装方法などではなく、App Store での規約やルールに対してという事でしょうか？

Comment: 実装、App Storeでリジェクトされないかの両方です。
特にリジェクトされないか気になってます。
アプリ内課金で提供する機能を、自サーバで勝手に判断して特定のユーザに提供することになるので。。。